# Why is this string empty?

Tags: c, string, function

I have this little problem, and can't solve it.
The thing is that I'm trying to load all four strings in the function `LOAD` by asking the user to insert it. Everything seems fine and I don't get any compiler error. But `eaf` stays **empty**. I tried many ways, even replacing `scanf` with `gets`, `gets_s`, `fgets`, but nothing changes.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void LOAD(char eaf[], char initials[], char finals[], char symbols[]);
int COMPARE(char s[], char eaf[]);

int main()
{
    char eaf[10],initials[1],finals[10],symbols[5];
    LOAD(eaf, initials, finals, symbols);
    return 0;
}


void LOAD(char eaf[], char initials[], char finals[], char symbols[])
{
    printf("Insert states of the optimized AFD\n");
    scanf( " %s", eaf);

    printf("Insert AFD initial state\n");
    do
    {
        scanf( " %s", initials);
    } while (COMPARE(initials, eaf));

    printf("Insert final state(s)\n");
    do
    {
        scanf( " %s",finals);
    } while (COMPARE(finals, eaf));

    printf("Insert the language symbols\n");
    scanf( " %s",symbols);
}

int COMPARE(char s[], char eaf[])
{
    int i;
    char *ptr;
    for(i; i < strlen(s); i++){
            printf("%d\n", i);
        while(ptr==NULL){
            ptr = strchr(eaf, *s);
        }
    }
    if (ptr == NULL) return 1;
    else return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? This is just a small part of a bigger program, but the rest of it is useless because `eaf` is empty. I thought that the problem was using `scanf`, but as I said other functions didn't work as well. I hope anyone can help me. Thanks

edit: I checked by `strlen(eaf)`

Comment: You forgot to initialize `i` in COMPARE. (Also, don't all-caps anything that isn't a `#define`d macro.)

Comment: Note: Never call `strlen` in a loop test. That requires `strlen` to loop through the whole string on every iteration. Many compilers can optimize that out, but when it happens to not be optimized, performance can drop like a rock. Compute the length once, outside the loop. (I'd complain about the fixed-size buffers and `scanf`, but fixing those is a lot more work.)

Comment: `initials[1]` and `scanf( " %s", initials);`. You overstep the array boundaries, and it looks like the 0-terminator for `initials` is written to `eaf`.

Comment: Your compare function is not really useful. Compile your program with `gcc -Wall -Werror ...`.

Comment: `while(ptr==NULL){` ptr is uninitialised in COMPARE()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using "scanf" for input is dangerous, and you've walked right into that danger. You're allowing it to overwrite the contents of "eaf" when you ask it to read initials as a string and it adds the terminating 0.

Ultimately, the string is empty because you got your array dimensions wrong. You gave "initials" an array size of 1 which does not provide space for the trailing '\0' C-string terminator.

See the live demo of this code on [ideone](http://ideone.com/hHRoOS):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void report(char* eaf, char* initials, char* foo)
{
    printf("eaf = %p, initials = %p, foo = %p\n", eaf, initials, foo);;
    printf("*eaf = %d, *initials = %d, *foo = %d\n", eaf[0], initials[0], foo[0]);
}

void load(char eaf[], char initials[], char foo[])
{
    printf("load\n");
    report(eaf, initials, foo);

    printf("Enter EAF\n");
    scanf(" %s", eaf);
    report(eaf, initials, foo);

    printf("Enter initial state\n");
    scanf(" %s", initials);
    report(eaf, initials, foo);
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    char eaf[10], initials[1], foo[10];
    report(eaf, initials, foo);
    load(eaf, initials, foo);
    report(eaf, initials, foo);

    return 0;
}
```

You should have walked thru this in the debugger and watched the values of "eaf" and "initials" to see what happened as you progressed.

Do you have to write this program in C? It seems that using a scripting language such as perl or python might be easier for you.

Here is a working C method to start solving the problem, note that I didn't actually fix the problem, but it will make it easier to see it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void report(char* eaf, char* initials, char* foo)
{
    printf("eaf = %p, initials = %p, foo = %p\n", eaf, initials, foo);;
    printf("*eaf = %d, *initials = %d, *foo = %d\n", eaf[0], initials[0], foo[0]);
}

void load(const char* label, const char* into, size_t intoSize)
{
    assert(intoSize > 1); // can't store a string in 1 character.
    printf("%s\n", label);

    char input[1024] = "";
    fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);

    size_t len = strlen(input);
    // strip trailing \n off.
    if (len > 0 && input[len - 1] == '\n') {
        input[--len] = 0;
    }

    // abort on empty input
    if (len <= 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input - terminated.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (len >= intoSize) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input - length was %u, limit is %u\n", len, intoSize - 1);
        exit(2);
    }

    strncpy(into, input, intoSize);
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    char eaf[10], initials[1], foo[10];
    report(eaf, initials, foo);

    load("Insert states of the optimized AFD", eaf, sizeof(eaf));
    report(eaf, initials, foo);

    load("Insert initial AFD state", initials, sizeof(initials));
    report(eaf, initials, foo);

    printf("eaf = %s\ninitials = %s\n", eaf, initials);

    return 0;
}
```

See live demo on [ideone here](http://ideone.com/UQiujj).

Comment: Oops - I had the assert the wrong way around in the copy I pasted here :)

Comment: Many thanks! You solved my problem, I believe it was in the array dimensions like you said. I took some other advices from your answer too. Actually I have a ground in Python, and in that language this would be far easier to do, but sadly I do have to write it in C. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You're format string in `scanf` is most likely the culprit; you have an **extra space** before the `%s`.

Change:

```
scanf( " %s", eaf);
```

to

```
scanf( "%s", eaf);
```

for all your `scanf`'s.

Its not putting your input into `eaf` because it is looking for a string of the format " **blahblahblah**" (note the space in the beginning) instead of "**blahblahblah**"

### Edit

Disregard the above,

> whitespace: Any whitespace characters trigger a scan for zero or more whitespace characters. The number and type of whitespace characters do not need to match in either direction.

Also, you should initialize `i` in your `COMPARE` function (I don't understand how you're not getting an angry warning from your compiler), I ran your code with no modifications and `strlen(eaf)` returned the correct count (just after the `scanf`).

Comment: Nope. Whitespace in a `scanf` format string means "skip any amount of whitespace".

Comment: @user2357112: Even no whitespace?

Comment: @user2357112 `whitespace: Any whitespace characters trigger a scan for zero or more whitespace characters. The number and type of whitespace characters do not need to match in either direction.` ... Crap, you're right; I missed the "zero or more" part...

Comment: It did not solve the main problem, but I appreciate your effort. And yes, I forgot to initialize `i` in the function `COMPARE`. Thanks!